# re-invoke collapsible effect with jquery after jquery AJAX response

Tags: spring, jquery, jsf-2

I have a collapsible rows effect in html table which is given via jquery. This works fine without the ajax poll, but when an ajax update happen the collapse effect wont work, is there anything that i'm doing wrong here.

Note:
sometimes when user clicks the + sign it changes to - sign but the rows doesn't show, and most of the time even this works for double click

.xhtml page

```
<tbody>
<ui:repeat var="trY" value="#{dataBean.bdata}">
<tr class="main-#{trY.symbol}">
<td><span id="more-#{trY.symbol}">
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{trY.has == '+'}">
    <a id="a-#{trY.symbol}" class="plus" href="#" style="color: black;" name="+">+</a>
    </ui:fragment>
    </span>
</td>
    </tr>
    <ui:repeat var="trB" value="#{trY.comp}" varStatus="st">
<tr class="orB-#{trY.symbol}">
<td class="tbl_column_buy1">
       <div class="qty_margins">
       <span id="orBbidQty-#{trY.symbol}#{st.index}">#{trB.bidQuantity}</span>
       </div>
</td>
<td class="tbl_column_buy2">
     <div class="qty_margins">
      <span id="orBbidPrice-#{trY.symbol}#{st.index}">#{trB.bidPrice}</span>
     </div>
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</ui:repeat>
</tbody>
```

JQuery scripts

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.orB').hide();
    $(".plus").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
                id = id.split('-');

        if($("#a-"+id[1]).html() == '+'){
            $(".orB-"+id[1]).show();
            $("#a-"+id[1]).html("-"); 
        }else if($("#a-"+id[1]).html() == '-'){
            $(".orB-"+id[1]).hide();
            $("#a-"+id[1]).html('+');
        }
        return false;
    });    
});

    function orBK(){
            $(".plus").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
                id = id.split('-');

        if($("#a-"+id[1]).html() == '+'){
            $(".orB-"+id[1]).show();
            $("#a-"+id[1]).html("-"); 
        }else if($("#a-"+id[1]).html() == '-'){
            $(".orB-"+id[1]).hide();
            $("#a-"+id[1]).html('+');
        }
        return false;
    });   
    }
    /* ajax timer to update */        
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var i = setInterval(function ()
                {

                    $.ajax({
                          type : "POST",
                          url : 'http://localhost:8080/myproject/faces/trade/dataPage.xhtml',
                          dataType : "json",

                          success: function(data) {


                           $.each(data, function(i, item) {


                 if(data[i].Has == "+" ){
                   $("span[id*='more-"+data[i].Symbol+"']").html("<a id='a-"+data[i].Symbol+"' class='plus' href='#' style='color: black;'>+</a>");
                 }
                 if(data[i].comp != null){
                    for(var j=0; j<data[i].comp.length; j++){
                        $("span[id*='orBbidQty-"+data[i].Symbol+""+j+"']").text(item.comp[j].BidQuantity);
                        $("span[id*='orBbidPrice-"+data[i].Symbol+""+j+"']").text(item.comp[j].BidPrice);
                    }
                 }
                        });   
                           $(".plus").unbind('click', orBK);
                           $(".plus").bind('click', orBK);
                          },
                          error : function() {
                            alert("Sorry, The requested property could not be found.");
                          }
                        });
                }, 4000);

});
```

Comment: Too much code. Moving on

Answer (score 0):

First, Javascript is case sensitive. Your function is named `orBK`, but in your AJAX update you rebind as `orBk`. Second, `orBK` assigns a click handler, but is itself assigning another click handler. Finally, look up jQuery delegate event binding (`.live` in older versions, `.on` in newer). You don't need to rebind your handlers.

Comment: i've corrected that mistake thanks, but its still does not work. When .live is used it works only after a refresh. .on never worked.

Comment: orBK still assigns a click handler in your code above. You should fix that too. Also, .on is the new way to bind all handlers, direct or delegated, and I've not had any problems with it.